# Using output of DSolve/NDSolve as a function with "variable" constants

Tags: differential-equations

I've already looked through the questions similar to this one, but I couldn't figure out how to modify them so that they work, and I suspect that there are deeper issues than just the syntax. Here is my code attempt:

```
fFunction[a_, b_, c_, z_] = 
 alpha[z] /. 
  First@DSolve[{c*
    alpha[z]*(alpha[z]^2 + alpha[z]) / ((alpha[z] + 1)^2 + b^2) - 
   1 == alpha'[z], alpha[0] == a}, alpha[z], z]
```

Basically there are four variables, where a,b,c are constants related to the physical apparatus which I'll put in later, and then alpha, which is the main variable I want to consider. Basically I want to solve the differential equation for alpha, which I suppose is actually a function of four variables. I understand how to do it for the one variable case, but this multivariable case, which I believe shouldn't be substantially harder, is eluding me.

Is the problem that Mathematica is trying to evaluate the inside first, but can't?

Comment: The difficulties you may be encountering are due primarily to the fact that `DSolve` is not returning an explicit solution for `alpha[z]`.  This has nothing to do with the three constants.  I would add that you should be careful when making `fFunction` an explicit function of `z`.

Comment: If I change it to NDSolve like this:　fFunction[a_, b_] = 
 alpha[z] /. 
  First@NDSolve[{alpha[
         z]*(alpha[z]^2 + alpha[z]) / ((alpha[z] + 1)^2 + b^2) - 1 == 
      alpha'[z], alpha[0] == a}, alpha[z], {z, 0.1, 10}], it has a different error where it says that a is not a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html):

```
zmax = 2;
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{c*alpha[z]*(alpha[z]^2 + alpha[z])/((alpha[z] + 1)^2 + b^2)-1 == alpha'[z],
alpha[0] == a}, alpha, {z, 0, zmax}, {a, b, c}]

Plot[pfun[1, 1, 1][ze], {ze, 0, zmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the perfect solution. I'll definitely keep this in my mathematica toolbox in the future.